# Firebase authentication with localId / idToken (instead of email / password)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

In my app, when a user logs in, I use firebase.auth to authenticate the user based on the email/password the user typed:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userInputs.email.value, userInputs.password.value)
```

Then I dispatch it to the redux state and also set the received localId and idToken on the local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem('token', response.user.qa);
localStorage.setItem('localId', response.user.uid);
```

When the user closes the app window and then reopen the app later, the localId and idToken are still set in the localstorage, but to re-authenticate I need to supply email and password. Is it possible to authenticate with localId/idToken, or should I save the email/password on localStorage instead of saving the two tokens?

Upon checking if the user is authenticated:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
console.log(user);
```

I get 'null'.
It seems that I must sign in even if I already have the localId, without signing in I don't have access to the database.

Also, obviously my database rules grant access to the db only to authenticated users:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have to reauthenticate the user upon reload, the tokens are automatically persisted, loaded upon reload, and then refreshed. All you should have to do is listen for `onAuthStateChanged`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: But the user isn't logged in after reentering the application. I'm talking about totally closing the window and then restarting the applciation.

I checked with: 

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            console.log(user);

And received 'null'. Doesn't it mean that I have to sign in again?
I do have the tokens stored in localStorage, but firebase cannot be accessed because there isn't an authenticated user when reentering
Thanks again in advance

Comment: Please try with `onAuthStateChanged`. If the token needs to be refreshed, that's an async opertion and `firebase.auth().currentUser` may not catch it.  On an `onAuthStateChanged` listener still doesn't work for you, update your question to show what you've tried with that. In that case it'd also help to know what platform (browser, phone, etc) you run on.

Comment: Thanks mate! I got it

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to store the email & password in the localstorage.
Firebase library automatically retain the auth infomation locally.

The cause of you get `null` is you are trying to get user info with Synchronous code.
Which means that you are trying to get user before the firebase library's initalization.

```
firebase.auth().currentUser; // <= synchronous
```

Following code runs Asynchronously and you can get user after the firebase library initalize.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```